# How to tell if a "ZipArchiveEntry" is directory?

Tags: .net, zip, system.io.compression

I am handling some 3rd party ZIP files with .Net 4.5.2 System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive class and all works nicely.
However, I need to tell apart **file entries** from **directory entries**, preferably without extracting them first.

**Is there a way to tell if a ZipArchive entry is a directory without extracting it?**

As far as could find out there is no property of ZipArchiveEntry that tells if it is a file or directory.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Seems like I really do tend to answer my own questions.

Anyway, the answer is straight forward:

**If `ZipArchiveEntry` is a directory it will have its `FullName` property ending with "/" (e.g. *"some_dir/"*) and its `Name` property will be empty string (*""*).**

If only someone cared to put that info in the documentation ...

Oh, and there is **a catch**:
If a directory contains files, there does **not** have to be a separate `ZipArchiveEntry` for it.
So, if you are looking for a specific directory you cannot just look for one `ZipArchiveEntry` with empty `Name` or with "/" at the end of `FullName` - you have to parse the whole tree (`FullName` for each `ZipArchiveEntry`).

Luckily I had only to check if there is a single common directory for all entries (`FullName` properties of all `ZipArchiveEntry` items shoud start with the same string in the form of "folder_name/").

Comment: To be safe I always check FullName for both '\' and '/', specially since ZipArchive itself is broken and will save whatever you throw at it without normalizing to using '/' as the standard says.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but I think it has a better solution than the one provided here.
ZipArchiveEntry has a property named ExternalAttributes. Looks like this has been available since .Net Framework 4.7.2

According to MS docs "...low order byte is the MS-DOS directory attribute byte...".

Therefore all you need to do is to take the low byte, cast it as FileAttributes and check the attributes if it is a "Directory" or not.

```
   var lowerByte = (byte)(atributeValue & 0x00FF);
   var attributes = (FileAttributes)lowerByte;
```

Now just check the attributes to see if it is a directory (folder)

```
if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)) {...}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

ICSharpZipLib does it like this:

```
    public bool IsDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            int nameLength = name.Length;
            bool result =
                ((nameLength > 0) &&
                ((name[nameLength - 1] == '/') || (name[nameLength - 1] == '\\'))) ||
                HasDosAttributes(16)
                ;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public bool IsFile
    {
        get
        {
            return !IsDirectory && !HasDosAttributes(8);
        }
    }
```

one could write these as extension methods for ZipArchiveEntry

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Zip/ZipEntry.cs) is the `ZipEntry` class for ICSharpZipLib on github