# C# Get top level files from zip file only

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get all the file names that are located in the top level of a zip file and not anything in subdirectories.

The code I'm currently using is

```
            using System.IO.Compression.ZipFile;

            using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(pathToZip))
            {
              foreach (var e in zip.Entries)
              {
                  var filename = e.Name;
              }
            }
```

But this code gets all the files in the zip. Any help is much apricated.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use [`FullName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.fullname?view=net-5.0) for this - _"The FullName property contains the relative path, **including the subdirectory hierarchy**, of an entry in a zip archive."_ - presumably if there's no hierarchy, then it's a top-level file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223451/how-to-tell-if-a-ziparchiveentry-is-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will extract only files that are not contained in a directory:

```cs
using (var zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(pathToZip))
{
    foreach (var e in zip.Entries.Where(e => !e.FullName.Contains("/")))
    {
        {
            var filename = e.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also check if Name is not IsNullOrWhiteSpace  because in this case name is empty string